# How to bundle a few small utilities into a single exe?

Tags: join, exe

I've written a Windows 7 batch file that "calls" two small audio processing utilities, Tag.exe and SHNTools.exe (to extract a CUE sheet frm a large FLAC file and split it into tracks) which I would like to bundle all together, including the .CMD file, into a single executable file for my own ease-of-use.  Is there a freeware that bundles small apps/programs/utils in this way?  Or failing that, what's the easiest way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one that does what I need:  Bat-to-Exe Convertor by F2KO Software, which packaged up the batch file and the two utilities into a single file and executed all three perfectly, as written and as called, when that new .exe file was run.